# Node.js and interacting with a native chat like Pidgin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmpp, pidgin

Is there a way to interact easily with a native messaging client (for example Pidgin) when using Node.js ?

I tried to create a simple chat system with the XMPP protocol with Node.js (with https://github.com/astro/node-xmpp then https://github.com/amiadogroup/candy). 
But I didn't work and it was complicated.

Comment: Seriously, use an XMPP library for this instead of hooking into a GUI client. Really.

Comment: I tried with node-xmpp, which is a XMPP library

Comment: Which part of node-xmpp didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another protocol like IRC. Relevant node module: [node-irc](https://github.com/martynsmith/node-irc)

Answer (score 0):

I created simple wrapper around pidgin dbus api: https://github.com/sidorares/node-pidgin